# Apply MediaTypeFormatter to a non-WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm exploring ways to generate different format of http response based on request parameters in ASP.NET MVC applications, and I was wondering if it is possible to use `MediaTypeFormatter`s to non-WebAPI controllers (i.e. to subclasses of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`).

`MediaTypeFormatter`s work wonderfully in WebAPI, but I haven't been able to find any information regarding the way and the place where they are injected into the MVC pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling my hair out for a day on this same question.  To accomplish the equivalent of a MediaTypeFormmater for MVC Controller classes, you can intercept the model binding.  This page describes how to do do that for XML.  My goal was to handle BSON. I didn't see a reason to create a REST service just to handle requests.  My client is HttpClient with extensions.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1261/custom-model-binder-aspnet-mvc

Be careful when checking the content type.  It can contain a character set, so I changed a line in GetBinder as follows:

```
    if (receivedContentType == null || !receivedContentType.StartsWith("application/bson"))
```